# How to match only equals pattern , in other word not contain pattern

Tags: java, regex

```
String allString = " I1 + I6 + I9 + I8 + I3 + I2 + I20 + I21 + I18 + I23 + I28 + I27 + I31 + I24 + I12 + I15 + I14 + I13 + I16 + I11 "
```

How i check only "I1" in java regular expression pattern. Input patterns is "I1" , "I6"..... "I11". In this case "I1" , "I12" , "I15" , "I14" , "I13" , "I16" "I11" are same "I1" input pattern. How to solve?

Comment: @AvinashRaj he wants same pattern like the number which contains I1* pattern so the regex might be `I1.\d*`

Comment: my question is how to check only match pattern

Comment: can you post some expected output and your attempts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple regex pattern `I1\d*` i.e. `I1` followed by any number of digits.

```
String allString = "...";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("I1\\d*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(allString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group() + ", ");
}
```

In Java, we need to escape the `\` too and so the final pattern will become `I1\\d*`.

***Output :***

```
I1, I18, I12, I15, I14, I13, I16, I11,
```

Answer (score 0):

`I1(?!\d)` will match I1 but not I11, I12 etc.

```
    String allString = " I1 + I6 + I9 + I8 + I3 + I2 + I20 + I21 + I18 + I23 + I28 + I27 + I31 + I24 + I12 + I15 + I14 + I13 + I16 + I11 ";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("I1(?!\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(allString);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

**Output:**

`I1`